# Not able to access google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I got the procedure for accessing google maps that we need to generate the system key and submit that key to the google api for the permission. I have successfully generated the system key by giving the path of the java and android debug key and got the Private key of the system. But while am giving the key to the google api, it is giving me some error like this 
[image: check this]

Do not know how to proceed.
Can any one help me?

Comment: i have added the screen shot like how am getting the error . As my system key page cannot be accessed by any one else. And tell me what all other information do you need to solve my problem

Comment: if you get system key then put it in http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and get genrated api key , copy it and continue with this doc ::: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: **caution :** if your system key is wrong then android cant able to view google map. and as per screen sort i understand that way of display map is totally wrong .

Comment: Ok. i understood that. But i have generated the key for many times in the mean which i getting the same key and tried to paste in the link you have given.

Comment: clear the cookies and caches of browser and then try.

Comment: I got the solution. May be it is silly but am not able to proceed only because of extra space that is there in the key generated. It may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

What version of JRE are you using? If you are on 7 it doesn't generate an MD5 hash by default instead it generates a SHA1. Adding -v after the -list will generate an MD5 instead of SHA1.

```
keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "Path to your keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```